# Does חֵטְא וְעָוֹן include violating positive commandments

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, mitzvah, sin

Do the words commonly mentioned in scripture E.g exedos 34,6 ֶפֶַשע חֵטְא וְעָוֹן specifically refer to negative commandments that one transgresses or do they include not performing positive commandments? how about if they are Rabinik?

Related sources please

For example [e"h 178.21](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.178.21) from the end of [rambam laws of sotah](http://www.chabad.org/960641/#footnoteRef46a960641):

> Whenever a person is not careful regarding [the conduct of] his wife, his sons and the members of his household, warning them, and scrutinizing their ways at all times so that he knows that they are perfect without **sin or transgression**, he is himself a sinner

Answer (score 1):

From Rosh hashana 17a it is clear someone who does not fulfill positive commandments is a פושע:

> ראש השנה י"ז: כי האנשים אשר לא הניחו על ראשם תפילין מעולם הם הנקראים פושעי ישראל בגופם, ועונשם חמור מן העובר פעם אחת על חייבי כריתות ומיתות בית דין
>    says refraining from putting on Tephilin on a constant basis they are called **פושע** can amount to more iniquity then someone who transgresses Chayvei krisus (sins which one dies under 60) and misos beis din (sins which one gets killed for).

Likewise the Gemora Yevamos 62b quotes the Questioners Posukhat a Person is a חוטא for not doing a negative Mitzva which has no action (which is not awarded Malkos as punishment):

> אמר ריב"ל כל היודע באשתו שהיא יראת שמים ואינו פוקדה נקרא **חוטא** שנאמר וידעת כי שלום אהלך ופקדת נוך ולא תחטא ואמר ריב"ל וחייב אדם לפקוד את אשתו בשעה שהוא יוצא לדרך שנא' וידעת כי שלום אהלך ופקדת נוך ולא תחטא'
>   If a person has a faithful wife and refrains indiscriminately from having relations with her (which is a Mitzva of עונתה לא יִגְרָע (שְׁמוֹת כא), י) he is a "sinner" as it says "And you shall know that Your house has peace and you shall frequent your wife"

Even someone who refuse Hashems Benevolence is called a חוטא as it says with regards to a Nazir who refrains from wine in Nazir 22a:

> תניא ר"א הקפר (בר רבי) אומר מה ת"ל (במדבר ו, יא) מאשר חטא על הנפש וכי באיזו נפש חטא זה אלא מפני שציער עצמו מן היין נקרא חוטא והלא דברים ק"ו ומה זה שלא ציער עצמו אלא מן היין נקרא חוטא המצער עצמו מכל דבר על אחת כמה וכמה
>   Why does it say "he has sinned for his soul"(Bamidbar 6,11) because he (the Nazir) has inflicted himself from drinking wine and how much more so someone who inflicted himself from all things.